# error: Error: Unable to resolve module `ahoefa11.png` from `Screens\HomeScreen.js`: ahoefa11.png could not be found within the project

Tags: firebase, react-native

error: Error: Unable to resolve module `ahoefa11.png` from `Screens\HomeScreen.js`: ahoefa11.png could not be found within the project.

this my code

```
import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage';


storage()
    .ref('ahoefa11.png')
    .getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
      console.log(url);
    });


const images = [
    require('ahoefa11.png'), 
    require('../assets/du1.jpg'),
    require('../assets/du2.jpg'),       
    require('../assets/du3.jpg'),     
];
```

this is my code im trying to take the image ahoefa11.png from firebase storage and use it in my homescreen

Answer (score 0):

**1) Check out how to get a download url correctly:** ( from https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files?authuser=0)
First, create a storage reference:

```
var storage = firebase.storage();
var storageRef = storage.ref();
```

Then, Create a reference to the file you want to download:

```
var starsRef = storageRef.child('images/stars.jpg');
```

Finally, Get the download URL, in the 'then' You recieve a url, and you can catch errors as well:

```
starsRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
   <insert here whatever code you would like, url is the image link)
 }).catch(error => {
<catch errors here if you want>
}
```

**2) Your error says:**

> error: Error: Unable to resolve module ahoefa11.png from
> Screens\HomeScreen.js: ahoefa11.png could not be found within the
> project.

**It means that the path to ahoefa11.png file in images array is incorrect.**
If this image is also in assets folder, images array should look like:

```
    const images = [
    require('../assets/ahoefa11.png'), 
    require('../assets/du1.jpg'),
    require('../assets/du2.jpg'),       
    require('../assets/du3.jpg'),
]
```